method to quickly delete unconnected interior faces?
Whenever I'm optimizing a mesh for a game I will always delete faces that will never be seen by the player, finding them usually takes a while to find depending on the complexity of the model, so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do it?, perhaps an addon?
Unfortunately "Select>Select all by trait>Interior faces" won't work because the two meshes are one object, but are not connected to each other by vertices


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Do you mind a GeometryNodes modifier ?
